# Convert object column to int column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I somehow have a strange conversion problem in python. I have an object column which I want to convert to an int column to save some memory space.

I run the following command:

```
df['Number'] = df['IntC'].astype(int)
```

and somehow for some rows it ends up like this:

```
IntC               Number
233004885002       -188830000475
233048850003       -195883838200
```

What is happening here? I would expect this output:

```
IntC               Number
233004885002       233004885002 
233048850003       233048850003
```

Comment: works well for me. you can also try `.astype('int64')`.

Answer (score 1):

If convert object to int , why not do factor

```
df['Number'] = df.IntC.factorize()[0]
```

Comment: somehow it gives the same error, `astype('int64') works

Answer (score 0):

Using Lambda function is a much-generalized option

```
df['Number'] = df.IntC.apply(lambda c: int(c))
```